# Failed - Download error. ideaIU - 2016.3.3.exe

Tags: intellij-idea, download

I'm downloading IDE for Java from here:

> https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/specials/idea/idea.html?&gclid=Cj0KEQiAk5zEBRD9lfno2dek0tsBEiQAWVKyuHcgJrEpvX3e9-i3ZHv-TdarErOvUR4XQDv-q0RjK5IaAqQU8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds.ds&dclid=CLmwjoX-2tECFVeVGAodfE0Gnw

After an hour of downloading the download is completed, but I'm getting the message Failed - Download. Can anyone suggest where the problem can be, please?

[image]

Comment: I have solved the problem by downloading not from Chrome, but from Opera.

Comment: normnorm normcc

Answer (score 0):

Click on *Show all* beside the download
You will see `chrome://downloads`:

[image]

Then right-click the link present below the name that you download
And then click *Copy URL*.

Then open other browser like MS Edge, then right-click on the search and click paste and go it will start downloading.